# Change text of all elements with specific data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm currently trying to use jQuery to change the text of a number of elements to the value of a specific data-attribute.

For example:

```
index.html
----------
<h1 data-change="text2">text1</h1>
<p data-change="paragraph2">paragraph1</p>
```

I want to change 'text1' to 'text2' and 'paragraph1' to 'paragraph2' (the value of data-change for that specific element).

How would I go about doing this?

I assumed I would be able to 'select' all of the elements with the data-attribute 'data-change' and then just do a simple `$(this).text($(this).data('change'));` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('[data-change]').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).data('change'));
});
```

You can iterate over the elements and change its text.

Comment: Even shorter: `$('[data-change]').text("some text here");` - Fron the docs: `The text to set as the content of each matched element.`

Comment: @DJDavid98, no he wants the particular data's value ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki This worked elegantly, thanks. I never think about the iterative functions of jQuery.

Comment: @LukeBennett, glad to have helped ;)

Answer (score 2):

`.text` method could accept a callback function.

```
$('[data-change]').text(function() {
  return $(this).data('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How would you like this~

-html-

```
   <select id="" name="" class="input_select">

          <option value="text2" selected="selected">text2</option>
           <option value="paragraph2">paragraph2</option>
   </select>

  <h1 class="text2">text1</h1>
   <p class="paragraph2">paragraph1</p>
 </pre>
```

-js-
    $(document).ready(function(){

`$('.input_select').change(function(){


        var valitem = $(this).val()

        if (valitem == 'text2')
        {
            $('.text2').text(valitem)

        }else{

            $('.paragraph2').text(valitem)

        }


    })
});`