# How to update html by finding a attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="person" data-chat="person1">
    <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/ih41k9tqr/img1.jpg" alt="" />
    <span class="name">user time</span>
    <span class="time">0:00 AM</span>
    <span class="preview">last message</span>
</li>
```

I have a actual time in var time. I want to replace value 0:00 AM to var time of person, who has attribute `data-chat="person1"`.

Comment: As is the age-old question... What attempts, if any, have you made in solving this issue? If you're just looking for the element with that attribute, you can do `$("[data-chat='person1']")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text of all elements with specific data-attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258618/change-text-of-all-elements-with-specific-data-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('[data-chat="person1"] .time').html(time.toString())
```

`$('[data-chat="person1"] .time')` will match the element with the class `.time` which is a child of the `[data-chat="person1"]` element selector.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
document.querySelector('["data-chat"="person1"] .time').innerHTML = '23:00 AM' // new time
```

Comment: When the question is tagged jQuery, it makes sense to use jQuery, as it's less verbose.